# I continue to get this error while attempting to create a new laravel applications. Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128

Tags: laravel, mcrypt

At first I was getting the MCRYPT error just by entering "Laravel" in the terminal, so I installed php, and MCRYPT with homebrew, and now when I enter in "Laravel" everything works smoothly.

Now when I attempt to create a new app I get this error.

```html
Crafting application...

Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed     'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83

Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes

Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/alexcruz/Code/site/config/app.php on line 83
Application key [uDNikuCU10cKrt18r5TjC21RWMiaprNT] set successfully.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

I've also installed Macport, and

sudo port install php55-mcrypt

sudo port install php54-mcrypt

added the extension to the end of the php.ini file
extension=/opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so

sudo apachectl restart

I've tried a bunch of different things. I've google the error, and tried to follow others examples, and no success.

I'm on a Mac running Yosemite.

Thank you

Comment: Does [this article](http://benohead.com/mac-os-x-php-notice-use-undefined-constant-mcrypt_rijndael_128/) help?

Comment: No, when I run brew install mcrypt
I get this error: Error: You must `brew link mhash' before mcrypt can be installed

Comment: did you try to brew link mhash? That's why it is recommended to use Homestead for Laravel, you don't have to deal with that. Everything is preconfigured for you!